# Save 1000s of data into mysql in most efficient way

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have almost 7000 data in mysql database. Some columns are empty and I want to fill them with related data. I am displaying the data from mysql and wrapped the empty fields with form and inserted inputs. The code is below;

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo '
<form action="" method="post">
    <tr>
        <td>'._date($row["time"]).'</td>
        <td>$row["name"]</a>
        <br><input name="name" class="form-control input-sm" value="New name" >
        </td>
        <td>info@domain.com<br>
        <input name="email" class="form-control input-sm" value="newemail@domain.com" >
        </td>
        <td>0123456789<br>
        <input name="telephone" class="form-control input-sm" value="0987654321" >
        </td>
        <td>111 Some street name<br>
        <input name="address" class="form-control input-sm" value="New road name and address" >
        </td>
        <td>category</td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-save fa-fw"></i></button>
            <a href="index.php?p=subscribers&delete='.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-fw"></i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
';}
```

As you can see i have the option of saving them individually but i also want to save all displayed data at once. displaying all the data can be very slow so i guess i need to display small part at a time.

Could anyone tell me have I can save all displayed form inputs at once?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: use one form, not a form per row, then a simple submit-> save

Comment: Once I use one form, how can I distinguish which input value will be saved into which row?

Comment: `name="name['.$row["id"].']"` or `name="data['.$row["id"].'][name]"` will make nice multi-d arrays you can play with

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Thank you Tadman, your comment helped me find the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing more research, I finally managed to find a solution and i am posting here for anyone who needs it.

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
    for($i=0; $i<count($_POST['id']); $i++){    
       $sql = "
        UPDATE test 
        SET 
            name        = '".$_POST['name'][$i]."',
            email       = '".$_POST['email'][$i]."',
            telephone   = '".$_POST['telephone'][$i]."' 
        WHERE id = '".$_POST['id'][$i]."'";

        if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            //echo "Record updated successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error updating record: " . $con->error;
        }

    }
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5";
$results = $con->query($sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
     echo '<form action="" method="post">';
     echo '<input type="hidden" name="update"  >';
    // displaying records.
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo '
            <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="'.$row["id"].'" >
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="name[]" class="form-control input-sm" value="'.$row["name"].'" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="email[]" class="form-control input-sm" value="'.$row["email"].'" ></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="telephone[]" class="form-control input-sm" value="'.$row["telephone"].'" ></td>
            </tr>
        ';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="update">';
    echo '</form>';
}else {
    echo "No records are found.";
}
```